# creating a class for something trivial ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

A Enum is coming back from the service layer with 1 out of 4 options and am using a case statement to handle it in my web code. I thought that I will be doing this at several places and to have some design pattern in place. Now based on each value from Enum I am doing is returning a string . creating a class for each enum seems to be a overkill. what is the best way to handle this

Comment: What do you mean each enum? How many types of enums are there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new subclass for each enum value, you can have multiple instances of the same class, one for each value:

```
public class MyEnumType {
  private readonly string value;

  private MyEnumType(string value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public string Value {
    get { return value; }
  }

  public static readonly MyEnumType ValueA = new MyEnumType("foo");
  public static readonly MyEnumType ValueB = new MyEnumType("bar");
  ...
}
```